# ASP.NETにて ListView をCSV, Excelにエクスポートする方法

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

GridViewをCSV化する方法はよく見かけますが、
ListViewもRowsやCellsに近いものを使用してCSVに出力が可能なのでしょうか。

現在はエクセル化のみ粗いですが動きました。

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=gv1.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    ListView1.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView`内の`i`行目の`T`型のコントロールにアクセスしたい場合は下記のような処理になります。

```
ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[i];
T control = item.FindControl("コントロールのID") as T;
```

このようにセルに当たる各コントロールを取得すれば`Text`その他のプロパティを加工し、CSVなりExcelなりに出力することは可能です。必要なら行に隠し項目を置いて出力用の情報を保持しておく手もあります。

なお質問文のコードで出力しているファイルはExcel形式ではないと思います。NPOI等に変更すべきではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！勉強になります。